# jQuery exclude custom word from Input's Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete

How to disable searching by custom word from Input's autocomplete?

For example, I want to prevent searching by the word "Student".

How can I exclude (ignore) this word from searching, but at the same time keep this word in Autocomplete and Input's value?

The script must work as now, but with exception word "Student" in Autocomplete.

Thank you!

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myNames = [
"Student David 22",
"Student Richard 20",
"Student Henry 21",
"Student Kraig 21",
"Student Jordan 22"
];
$(".myInput").autocomplete({
source: myNames
});
}
</script>


<input type="text" class="myInput" onkeydown="myFunction();" placeholder="Enter name" />
```

Comment: Remove 'Student' from the data, then add it to the result via css or by extending the _renderItem method.

Comment: No, it does not fit. "Student" in my script is only an example. I need some function like exception (ignoring) custom word.

Comment: Then the jQueryUI autocomplete plugin is likely not a good fit for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to stop the searching or the auto-completion when the user searched for the word `Student` 
Use it like this

```
  var myNames = [
     "Student David 22",
     "Student Richard 20",
     "Student Henry 21",
     "Student Kraig 21",
     "Student Jordan 22"
  ];

  $(".myInput").keyup(function(){
     var text = $(this).val();
     if (text.indexOf("Student") == -1 && text.indexOf("student") == -1 ) {
         $(".myInput").autocomplete({
            source: myNames
         });
      }else{
      $(".myInput").autocomplete("destroy");
      }
  });
```

When the word "Student" is being searched then the suggestion or the auto-compete stops
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzhosL49/1/)

Comment: Can you upload your script on jsfiddle. Maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you! But still script doesn't work as needed. Yes, autocomplete stops after typing full word "Student". But in the procese, when i'm typing this word, autocomplete is still working. How to prevent searching by this word on the fly?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? I wrote: "How can I exclude (ignore) this word from searching".

Comment: @Iwww eh, no, it's not that obvious. "st" is not "student", what you're actually looking for is excluding matches from your result set that are part or all of a given word. You essentially need to strip the given excluded words from the resultset before performing a search. jQuery UI has no such functionality nor does it have a method you can override to provide such functionality.

Comment: if you'll type student then any other word after it, the search will stop, no matter what user puts in the field after the word studetn